# Google Sheets and Script REALLY SLOW compared to Excel and VBA

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an Excel s/s which has some simple VBA in the background that I wrote myself.  Table inside has about 5000 rows by 6 columns and depending on user selection looks at rank of how often a particular word or character appears - it's a language tool.  The macros simply allow the user to increase rank by one each time; reveal answers line by line; or start from beginning (set rank back to 1).  Works fine in VBA and quickly too.

However I want to share with Mac people who don't have Excel!  I have a working version in Google Sheets with script which also works - programming in script wasn't too difficult to pick up as this was pretty basic and I have VBA background.  Example of script below though I don't think that's the issue - probably my understanding of how google script works in general.

Firstly just adjusting the choice of study level taken 15 seconds (that doesn't depend on script) - excel it's about 5sec - there are lots of countifs and rank formula.  However in VBA running any of the code takes under 1sec.  In script it takes 11 sec.  I can't believe the speed differences!

I have made several copies of the s/s so I can play with developing and see what optimises the calculations (not the script - there's not too much to optimise there) - and notice all share the same script - this is alien to me as in VBA the code stays with the s/s.  Is this one of the issues?

Why is Google Sheets so slow?

Simple code functions:

```
function IncreaseRankSelection(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if (spreadsheet.getRange('Q13').getValues()=="Yes"){
    spreadsheet.getRange('K3:M67').activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList
    ().setFontColor('#ffffff') }
  else {
    spreadsheet.getRange('K3:M67').activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setFontColor('#999999') }  

  if (spreadsheet.getRange('Q8').getValues()==spreadsheet.getRange('Q5').getValues()){
    Browser.msgBox('There are no more Sets to study!')}
  else {
    var startvalue = spreadsheet.getRange('Q8').getValues();
    var newvalue = (Number(startvalue) + 1);
    spreadsheet.getRange('Q8').setValue(newvalue);
  };

  spreadsheet.getRange('T17').setValue('1'); 
  newvalue2=spreadsheet.getRange('T10').getValues();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Q9').setValue(newvalue2);
  spreadsheet.getRange('Q8').activate();

};
```

Comment: There are plenty of things that can be optimized in your script. Your vba background is a liability than a asset. There are stuff you shouldn't do here as it's a entirely new language running in the cloud.

Comment: For formulas, you should use `ARRAYFORMULA`, `QUERY`, `VLOOKUP` in a array as a single formula rather than INDEX/MATCH and multiple formulae. Query in particular would be extremely fast.

Comment: Thanks so much - will learn and try all these sequentially see which makes most difference

Comment: Try this:`function IncreaseRankSelection(){var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();if (sh.getRange('Q13').getValues()=="Yes"){sh.getRange('K3:M67').setFontColor('#ffffff');}else {sh.getRange('K3:M67').setFontColor('#999999');}if (sh.getRange('Q8').getValue()==sh.getRange('Q5').getValue()){Browser.msgBox('There are no more Sets to study!')}else {sh.getRange('Q8').setValue(sh.getRange('Q8').getValue()+1);};sh.getRange('T17').setValue('1');sh.getRange('Q9').setValue(sh.getRange('T10').getValue());}`

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be optimized. You don't need to activate each range to use it, and it's better if you use [getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()) for single cells instead of [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) wich returns a 2D array. Also, there is no need to use a Range List, you can apply the [background color](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor) directly into the range. If you are going to access the same range several times, it's also a good practice to save it in a variable so it doesn't have access the object through the Spreadsheet each time:

```
    function IncreaseRankSelection(){
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var rangeQ8 = spreadsheet.getRange('Q8');
      var rangeK3M67 = spreadsheet.getRange('K3:M67');

      if (spreadsheet.getRange('Q13').getValue()=="Yes"){
        rangeK3M67.setFontColor('#ffffff');
         }
      else {
        rangeK3M67.setFontColor('#999999') 
      }  

      if (rangeQ8.getValue() == spreadsheet.getRange('Q5').getValue()){
        Browser.msgBox('There are no more Sets to study!')}
      else {
        var startvalue = rangeQ8.getValue();
        var newvalue = (Number(startvalue) + 1);
        rangeQ8.setValue(newvalue);
      };

      spreadsheet.getRange('T17').setValue('1'); 
      newvalue2 = spreadsheet.getRange('T10').getValue();
      spreadsheet.getRange('Q9').setValue(newvalue2);
      rangeQ8.activate(); 

    }
```

If you are using lots of formulas, you might be interested in using [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue) instead of getvalue, in case you only need the value displayed in the cell.

Another option would be the [batchupdate requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) of the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest), which are faster than the SpreadsheetApp when making changes to a Sheet.